# Change permalink for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have a page called Food which displays posts from 2 custom post types - Recipes and Restaurants.

How do I add 'food' to the permalink just for those two custom post types? - e.g. www.mysite.com/food/recipes/thepost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the rewrite parameter for [register_custom_post_type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). 
You may specity a slug that will be added before. So if you have two separate post types for recipes and restaurants set for one '/food/recipes' and for the second one '/food/restaurants'.
You must visit the Settings->Permalinks after this is done so that the rewrite rules will refresh.